# Cheap SSD: Slow Speed Issue

Tags: ssd, performance, benchmarking

In the beginning of the year I've bought a cheap SSD SomnAmbulist 120GB. After a couple of benchmarks, I've noted some strange throughput measurements. Briefly:

- **Initial Benchmark** | [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vObJQ.jpg)
  Just after format, the throughput is according to the advertised specifications at 510MB/s read and 440MB/s write.
  It starts to drop at 35% capacity written and stabilizes at 200~300MB/s read and 40MB/s write.
  Although this drop is not mentioned by the seller's ads, it is indeed an expected behavior and should return to normal after a couple of minutes in idle (flush the cache into the permanent area).
- **Benchmark after 1 hour in idle** | [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQvO4.jpg)
  Unfortunately, the throughput has not returned to normal (yet?).
  315MB/s read and 440MB/s write, and the speed drop started earlier at 10% capacity written.
- **Benchmark after 12 hours in idle** | [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdSQS.jpg)
  The throughput still has not returned to normal.

**Questions**

1. Is this the expected behavior for such cheap SSD or indeed there is something strange?
2. What might be going wrong here?
3. Any idea how to fix this throughput?

---

**Debug Info**

- SSD/TRIM Supported
- fstrim enabled
- SSD APM (Advanced Power Management) not supported
- f3 (Fight Flash Fraud) OK

```
## SSD/TRIM SUPPORTED
root@debian:~# hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep -i "trim\|power"
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
       *    Deterministic read data after TRIM


## SSD/TRIM AVAILABLE (DISC-MAX NON ZERO)
root@debian:~# lsblk -D /dev/sda
NAME DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
sda         0      512B       2G         0


## ADVANCED POWER MANAGEMENT NOT SUPPORTED
root@debian:~# hdparm -B /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 APM_level  = not supported



## FSTRIM ENABLE

root@debian:~# systemctl status fstrim.timer
● fstrim.timer - Discard unused blocks once a week
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Sat 2022-12-03 03:36:10 UTC; 35min ago
    Trigger: Mon 2022-12-05 00:51:25 UTC; 1 day 20h left
   Triggers: ● fstrim.service
       Docs: man:fstrim

Dec 03 03:36:10 debian systemd[1]: Started Discard unused blocks once a week.


root@debian:~# systemctl status fstrim
● fstrim.service - Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ● fstrim.timer
       Docs: man:fstrim(8)


root@debian:~# fstrim -av
```

Comment: Try to TRIM the entire drive. Format it for a good measure, then fstrim.

Comment: @gronostaj You are correct. Manually TRIM seems to solve the issue. But I'm still running some benchmarks to confirm. Tks!

Comment: Is TRIM definitely enabled by your OS? https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization#Mounting_SSD_filesystems

Comment: @Mokubai Yes, for sure TRIM is enabled for weekly schedule. And this was the problem. After a long write performed by the benchmark, it becomes necessary to manually trim in order to return to the original throughput.

Comment: Ah, well that sadly is standard for modern SSDs. Be aware though that repeatedly benchmarking the drive will be unnecessarily using up write cycles. If your drive is mostly full and you are benchmarking what is left without giving the wear leveller time to work across the rest of the drive then you could be working it into an early grave.

Comment: @Mokubai > "well that sadly is standard for modern SSDs.": I though this would be true only for cheap SSD ...

Comment: Writing a lot will slow down every SSD until it has caught up with erasing blocks it doesnt matter if they are expensive or not, they all have to take time to erase blocks once every block is used up. Some might be better at rearranging stuff in the background but they all still need to do it. On top of that NVME SSDs have a cache of fast NAND above their slower "bulk" NAND, and will be slow during benchmarks until the controller empties that cache, so you might be able to write 8 or 16 GB of data but once you hit it then that smaller section will be slow until erased or emptied.

Comment: Is the `discard` option present in the `fstab` entry for this drive/partition ?

Comment: @PierU No, `discard` is not present. I'm pretty sure TRIM is not set continuously, instead is set weekly.

Comment: OK, so this explains the observed behavior

Comment: discard is on by default for most if not all filesystems though, AFAIK. Instead of fstab, one should check the output of `findmnt` (or `mount` if you insist).

Comment: @TomYan "_Continuous TRIM is not the most preferred way to issue TRIM commands among the Linux community. For example, Ubuntu enables periodic TRIM by default, Debian does not recommend using continuous TRIM and Red Hat recommends using periodic TRIM over using continuous TRIM if feasible._", **Arch Linux Wiki**

Comment: @PierU > "this explains the observed behavior": Agree. Manual TRIM seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: My point was fstab does not necessarily reflect what mount option you are using, because there are default options. However, it seems that my memory about discard is universally on by default is wrong, probably because I had used f2fs for a long time (where discard IS on by default). Somehow I have a strong memory that it was once true for btrfs as well, but I couldn't find any proof. Either way, also see [this](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Btrfs-Async-Discard-Default)